# Thunderbird Lightning - Google Calendar : Synchronization issues

Tags: thunderbird, sync, calendar, google-calendar

Ubuntu 18.04.2 - 64bit,
Thunderbird 60.9.0,
Lightning calendar 6.2.9,
Provider for Google Calendar 4.4.2,

When adding a event in calendar using Google it appears in Lightning after hitting the synchronization button. Deleting the event in Lightning deletes also the event in Google calendar (after synchronization).
When adding an event into Thunderbird Lightning and synchronizing (to get it in Google) nothing happens.

Thus:
    Google → Thunderbird Lightning synchronization works.
    Events created in Google, synchronized to Lightning, can be deleted in Lightning and disappear in Google.
    Events created in Lightning DO NOT synchronize into Google.

Somebody an idea why?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check calendar **Properties** in Thunderbird. (Go to Calendar tab; select your Google calendar on the **Calendar** list on the left; right click on it; and select **Properties**; ensure that it is *not* **Read Only**)

Comment: @FedonKadifeli thanks for the suggestion.
Calendars are not read only, the read only box is not ticked in properties of the calendar.

Comment: - Downloaded the .tar.bz2 file from Thunderbird's website.
- Closed Thunderbird
- Unzipped it in /usr/lib